# Java - Regex problem

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a list of URLs of type

- `http://www.example.com/pk/ca`,
- `http://www.example.com/pk`,
- `http://www.example.com/anthingcangoeshere/pk`, and
- `http://www.example.com/pkisnotnecessaryhere`.

Now, I want to find out only those URLs that ends with `/pk` or `/pk/` and don't have anything in between `.com` and `/pk`

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Give many more examples of what you do want to match and what you don't want to match.

Comment: It's still not clear. Does the URL have to contain `.com`?

Comment: @Mark yes, it should contain `.com`

Comment: Maybe you mean “URLs that’s path is `/pk` or start with `/pk/`” or “URLs that’s first path segment is `pk`”?

Comment: This is a very useful page to learn regex: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Comment: How are we going to give you the pattern in regex if we don't even know what it is even in plain English? Explain it to us clearly through examples and careful wording, then we'd happily translate it to regex for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't fully defined so I can't give you an exact answer but this should be a start you can use:

```
^[^:]+://[^/]+\.com/pk/?$
```

These strings will match:

```
http://www.example.com/pk
http://www.example.com/pk/
https://www.example.com/pk
```

These strings won't match:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/pk
http://www.example.com/pk/ca
http://www.example.com/anthingcangoeshere/pk
http://www.example.com/pkisnotnecessaryhere
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String pattern = "^http://www.example.com/pk/?$";
```

Hope this helps.

Some details: if you don't add `^` to the beginning of the pattern, then `foobarhttp://www.example.com/pk/` will be accepted too. If you don't add `$` to the end of the pattern, then `http://www.exampke.com/pk/foobar` will be accepted too.

Answer (score 1):

Directly translating your request "[...] URLs that ends with /pk or /pk/ and don't have anything in between .com  and /pk", with the additional assumption that there shall always be a ".com", yields this regex:

If you use `find()`:

```
\.com/pk/?$
```

If you use `matches()`:

```
.*\.com/pk/?
```

Other answers given here give more restrictive patterns, allowing only URLs that are more close to your examples. Especially my pattern does not validate that the given string is a syntactically valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "^https?://(www\.)?.+\\.com/pk/?$";
```