# Java - Regex problem

Tags: java, regex, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Regex problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661849/java-regex-problem)

I have list of URLs of types:

- `http://www.example.com/pk/etc`
- `http://www.example.com/pk/etc/`
- `http://www.example.com/pk/etc/etc`

where `etc` can be anything.

So I want to search only those URLs that contains `www.example.com/pk/etc` or `www.example.com/pk/etc/`.

> Note: It is for all those who think that it is a duplicate question -- Kindly read both the questions carefully before marking this question as duplicate. Even after reading you can't understand that both the questions are different, then kindly leave without marking it as duplicate because I can't tell you the diff. in anymore detail

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661849/java-regex-problem

Comment: You know that if a string contains `www.example.com/pk/etc/` it also contains `www.example.com/pk/etc` since that’s a prefix of `www.example.com/pk/etc/`.

Comment: @Cletus Look at the questions carefully... both are diff. questions

Comment: @Yatendra Goel: Then please tell us the difference.

Comment: @Gumbo But the inverse is not true....

Comment: @Yatendra Goel: The problem is not it Java. The problem is hole in your understanding of RegEx. Please go back to other question. You may read more on http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @cletus @Gumbo This time the url can should contain `etc` at the end where the `etc` can be anything but in the previous question, the url should end with a fixed word `pk` or `pk/`

Comment: Maybe you should do a more systematical approach than regular expressions. Java has an excellent *URI* class that can be used to parse and process URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String pattern = "http://www.example.com/pk/[^/]+/?$";
```

I am assuming http://www.example.com/pk// is not accepted. If this should be accepted too, then use

```
String pattern = "http://www.example.com/pk/[^/]*/?$";
```

Comment: @Bytecode `+` means "one or more" or "zero or more" ?

Comment: @Yatendra: `+` means "one or more"

Comment: @Bytecode... I think tha it will also match http://www.example.com/pk/anything/anything .... If it is true, then it is not acceptable...
the url must have only one `/.../` or `/...` segment after `pk`

Comment: Then you should add $ after the ?: "http://www.example.com/pk/[^/]+/?$". Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Note that in regular expressions `.` means any character. If you mean a literal dot then you must escape it.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for reminding it... I and (@Bytecode) forgot it...

Comment: @Bytecode Can you update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't fully defined so I can't give you an exact answer but this should be a start you can use:

```
^[^:]+://[^/]+\.com/pk/[^/]+/?$
```

The difference is that the `/` is no longer optional and there must be at least one more character after `pk/`.

These strings will match:

```
http://www.example.com/pk/ca
http://www.example.com/pk/ca/
https://www.example.com/pk/ca/
```

These strings won't match:

```
http://www.example.com/pk//
http://www.example.co.uk/pk/ca
http://www.example.com/pk
http://www.example.com/pk/
http://www.example.com/anthingcangoeshere/pk
http://www.example.com/pkisnotnecessaryhere
http://www.example.com/pk/ca/sf
```

Comment: @Mark Yes, you are right that atleast one more character must be there after `pk/`. There should be only one segment `/...` or `/.../` after `pk` and not more than one... so http://www.example.com/pk/ca/sf must not be matched

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to search only those URLs that contains `www.example.com/pk/etc` or `www.example.com/pk/etc/`.

### Update

I think this will work:

`https?://.*\\.?[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.com/pk/etc/?[^.]`

But every item in the list you gave contains what you are searching for.